# Java Socket Bridge unable to connect

Tags: java, javascript, php, sockets

I have a project for varsity where we should use Java Socket Bridge to connect to a chat server (that is how I understand the project at least).

So according to [this](https://github.com/ihilt/JavaSocketBridge) github page, you should add this to your head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="java_socket_bridge.js"></script>
```

and this to your body

```
<applet id="JavaSocketBridge" archive="JavaSocketBridge.jar" code="JavaSocketBridge.class" width="0" height="0"></applet>
```

I have done so and I also ran the make.sh file to produce the jar file.
Here is my php file:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="java_socket_bridge.js"></script>
        <title>ValidateLogin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $ip = $_POST['ip'];
            $port = $_POST['port'];
            $_SESSION['sid'] = session_id();
            $_SESSION['ip'] = $ip;
            $_SESSION['port'] = $port;
            // header("location: Game.php");
            echo '  <applet id="JavaSocketBridge" code="JavaSocketBridge.class" archive="JavaSocketBridge.jar" height="0" width="0"></applet>';
            echo "  <script>
                        console.log(document.getElementById('JavaSocketBridge'));
                        if(socket_connect('".$ip."', '".$port."'))
                        {
                            console.log('connected!');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log('not connected!');
                        }
                    </script>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my problem is that when I call the socket_connect() function my web console displays

> "Java Socket Bridge cannot connect until the applet has loaded"
>   "not connected!"

I have tried calling the java_socket_bridge_ready() function (although it was not specified to do so) and then the web console displays:

> TypeError: get_java_socket_bridge(...).connect is not a function

on line 39 of the java_socket_bridge.js file.

I can't find any help on Google on this issue I've been looking all day. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and the latest firefox and XAMPP to run my webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I have to enable Java in my browser. I used [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml) page from Java's website on how to install and enable Java in my browser.